# English Sentence to Prolog clauses?

Tags: prolog

I am learning about Prolog recently and I came up with a question.

How do I say:

Any Employee drives, walks, rides or flies to work in Prolog clauses?

"Any" is where I am having problem with.

---

Here is my thought process.

```
Employee(tom).     %tom is an employee (fact)

drives(X) :- Employee(X).    
walks(X) :- Employee(X).    
rides(X) :- Employee(X).   
flies(X) :- Employee(X).
```

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: you should use lower case for your predicate names

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the other way around:

```
employee(X):- drives(X).
employee(X):- walks(X).
employee(X):- rides(X).
employee(X):- flies(X).
```

Plus facts for `drives`, `walks`, etc.

Whichever employee it is, one of these must hold. If it doesn't, then `employee(X)` fails.

This is, then, what it means *under this Prolog database*, that "any employee either flies, rides, etc.".

What you've written means, that given an `X` such that `employee(X)` holds, each of `drives(X)`, `walks(X)`, etc., will hold as well. I.e. "any employee walks, and drives, and rides, and flies" to work. (and of course, predicates must start with a lower case letter, always).